# Create heatmap with number as x and y axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heatmap in ggplot.

In the heatmap the x and y-axes should be numbers, however, whenever I change the row and column names to numbers the plot treats the numbers as some kind of scale.

Here's an example:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

nRow <- 9
nCol <- 16

myData <- matrix(rnorm(nRow * nCol), ncol = nCol)

rownames(myData) <- 1:nRow
colnames(myData) <- 1:nCol

# Replace with numbers that actually have a relationship:
for(ii in 2:ncol(myData)){  myData[, ii] <- myData[, ii-1] + rnorm(nrow(myData))  }
for(ii in 2:nrow(myData)){  myData[ii, ] <- myData[ii-1, ] + rnorm(ncol(myData))  }

# For melt() to work seamlessly, myData has to be a matrix.
longData <- melt(myData)

# Define palette
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")), space="Lab")

zp1 <- ggplot(longData,
              aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value))
zp1 <- zp1 + geom_tile()
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100))
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
zp1 <- zp1 + coord_equal()
zp1 <- zp1 + theme_bw()
print(zp1)
```

The same thing works perfectly if I replace row and column names with letters[1:nCol] and letters[1:nRow]

I tried adding the numbers as:

`colnames(myData)<-c("1","4","6"`...etc but that didn't help.

Comment: Try converting Var1 and Var2 to (ordered) factor.

Comment: `aes(x = factor(Var2), y = factor(Var1), fill = value))` and change the labels with `labs(x=…, y=…)`